# How to open a file on a server using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-ec2, fs

I'm using a Node.js script to read and return a random line from a .txt file using this function:

```
function pickMeal(){
var meals = fs.readFileSync('meals.txt','utf8');
var mealsArray = meals.toString().split('\n');
return mealsArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*mealsArray.length)];
}
```

On my desktop, it works fine. When I upload both the .js file and the .txt file to a folder on a server, suddenly I get an `Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'meals.txt'`.

I'm using an Amazon EC2 server, the .js script and the .txt file are in the same directory. Maybe there's something wrong with the permission of the .txt file?

I have already tried directing the script to `~/folder/meals.txt` or even the entire http link of the file, but I get the same result.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node is going to to try and read the file from the system root. You have to give the full path name.

```js
var path = require('path');
var txtpath = path.join(__dirname, 'folder_where_txt_file_is', 'txtfile.txt');
// now you can read the txt path
```